# AWS RDS postgresql performance

Tags: postgresql, performance, amazon-web-services

We have around 90 million rows in a new Postgresql table in an RDS instance. It contains 2 numbers, start_num and end_num(Bigint, mostly finance related) and details related to those numbers. The PK is on the start_num and end_num and table is CLUSTERed on this. The query will always be range query. Input will be a number and the output will be range in which this number is falling along with details. For eg: There is a row which has start_num=112233443322 and end_num as 112233543322. The input comes in as 112233443645. So the row containing 112233443322, 112233543322 needs to be returned.

**select start_num, end_num from ipinfo.ipv4 where input_value between start_num and end_num;**

This is always going into seq scan and the PK is not getting used. I have tried creating separate indexes on start_num and end_num desc but not much change in time. We are looking for an output of less than 300 ms. Now, I am wondering if that is even possible in Postgresql for range queries on large data sets or this is due to the Postgresql being on AWS RDS.
Looking forward to some advice on steps to improve the performance.

Comment: `in a new Postgresql table` Did you run `vacuum analyze new_table` on it? (not sure if amazon supports it)

Comment: You can run `EXPLAIN` on the query from the `psql` command line and see if your indexs are working the way you expect.  As @wildplasser said, also make sure you've done an analyze on the table.